# Stationary points of an ODE-system (again)

Tags: mathematical-modeling

There is another exercise where I am given a non-linear system of ODEs and a question that confuses me:

Consider $$x'=x(y+1)\\ \text{ and }\\ y'=xy+2.$$

> "Determine stationary points of the system, and linearize the system
>   at the stationary points, determine the geometric type of the
>   linearizations and the stability."

The only stationary point is $(x=2,y=-1)$. For the stability, I wrote $$f(x)=x(y+1),\\ g(y)=xy+2,$$ then differentiated: $$f'(x)=y+1,\\ g'(y)=x.$$
At $(-1,2)$, these values are $0$ and $2$. For $f$, I wrote that we cannot use linear terms in the expansion and hence would have to consider $f''$ and so on. For $g$, since it's greater than zero, the point is not linearly stable in $y$-direction.

But what is meant by "determine the geometric type of the linearizations"? What are types of linearizations? What am I missing here?

all the best,

Marie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the stability you should evaluate the Jacobi matrix (see my comment [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144273/linearization-for-differential-equation/144297#144297)). The geometric type of linearization is determined by the eigenvalues of this matrix. You can start learning these matters, e.g., [here](http://cazelais.disted.camosun.bc.ca/262/phaseplane.pdf).